# Confused on how to access the local path after select a file by react. Can I get it by e.target.file or something else?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

Here is my code:
The key thing is the handlefileupload. I'm not familiar with the e.target.file[0]. And I want to try to access the local path of the selected file by using e.target.file. But, I don't know how. If can't, are there have any other method to do that. The reason I want to access the path is to convert csv to json file.

After I get the path, I want to use this package 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-csv-to-json' to convert it to json file.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';

function App() {

const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

// process CSV data
const processData = dataString => {
    const dataStringLines = dataString.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    const headers = dataStringLines[0].split(/,(?![^"]*"(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);

    const list = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < dataStringLines.length; i++) {
        const row = dataStringLines[i].split(/,(?![^"]*"(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);
        if (headers && row.length === headers.length) {
            const obj = {};
            for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                let d = row[j];
                if (d.length > 0) {
                    if (d[0] === '"')
                        d = d.substring(1, d.length - 1);
                    if (d[d.length - 1] === '"')
                        d = d.substring(d.length - 2, 1);
                }
                if (headers[j]) {
                    obj[headers[j]] = d;
                }
            }

            // remove the blank rows
            if (Object.values(obj).filter(x => x).length > 0) {
                list.push(obj);
            }
        }
    }

    // prepare columns list from headers
    const columns = headers.map(c => ({
        name: c,
        selector: c,
    }));

    setData(list);
    setColumns(columns);
}

// handle file upload

const handleFileUpload = e => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    console.warn(file);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (evt) => {
        /* Parse data */
        const bstr = evt.target.result;
        const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });
        /* Get first worksheet */
        const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
        const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
        /* Convert array of arrays */
        const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(ws, { header: 1 });
        processData(data);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}

return (
    <div>
        <input
            type="file"
            accept=".csv,.xlsx,.xls"
            onChange={handleFileUpload}
        />

        <DataTable
            pagination
            highlightOnHover
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
        />
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Use e.target.value to get the path

Comment: Btw, I'm confused about like how to use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-csv-to-json. But after I enter the two commands of npm, it showed like cannot find that module. Do you know why it happened?  The code I added is let csvToJson = require('convert-csv-to-json');

Comment: Check your package.json to see if the package is installed

Comment: yeah... the most confusing thing is that the package.json has that

Comment: And btw, why does the target.value get the path is C:\fakepath\Book1.csv. How can I get the real local path?